# GNU Screen makes Vim ESC key slow

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

Screen makes my <kbd>ESC</kbd> key wait for more commands I believe, and if it does not get those commands, it sends it to my terminal session (which I am running VIM in).   <kbd>ESC</kbd> is used a lot in VIM and currently I do not make any use of the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key in Screen.

How would I go about changing the timeout?

I have read that these commands below inside of .screenrc  should fix it, but it doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
maptimeout 0
defc1 off
```

Comment: FWIW I don't see any such delay when running `vim` under `screen` myself.  I've got a more or less vanilla screen set up, subject to the defaults used in Ubuntu 10.10. ————— This sort of thing would happen if you've got a mapping set to `Esc`-something.  Maybe scan through the output from `:map` to check that.

Comment: When you do "ctrl-a i", do you see "-flow" or "+flow"? Or try running screen w/o your .screenrc to see if this still happens.

Comment: `maptimeout 0` alone should be enough. Do you also have a delay outside vim? Inside screen, is the delay the same duration as the `maptimeout` setting?

Comment: If I were you, I would use `tmux`.

Comment: `maptimeout 0` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

[**Here**](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/GNU_Screen_integration#Getting_the_Esc_key_to_work) is a post I found on [VIM Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki) that shows how to fix most GNU screen/VIM integration problems.

Correct command is `maptimeout 5`

> This may be necessary so Screen will *wait no more than 5 milliseconds* between characters when detecting an input sequence.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that this should go in `~/.screenrc` or `/etc/screenrc` (for all users), and you should then restart your screen session.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the screen key binding away from esc to something like ctrl. I have not experienced anything like what you are describing with the default binding in .screenrc in AIX, Fedora, Debian, or Ubuntu.