# ESC key causes a small delay in terminal due to its Alt+ behavior

Tags: vim, zsh, keyboard, tmux, gnome-terminal

My terminal setup is gnome-terminal + tmux + zsh with vi bindings.

In applications like vim or even in the zsh's command line vi editing mode, I need to frequently hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key but there is a small delay before the effects of this key take place. See [GNU Screen makes Vim ESC key slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/gnu-screen-makes-vim-esc-key-slow)

After some experimentation, I found that hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> key and immediately another key (say <kbd>b</kbd>) has the same effect as hitting <kbd>Alt+b</kbd>. I don't know why this is the case (probably for legacy reasons when there was no <kbd>Alt</kbd>? I don't know). Either way, I have two <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys and I don't want this behaviour with my <kbd>ESC</kbd> key. I have tried with <kbd>C+[</kbd> and its the same problem with that too.

I'm not sure who is responsible for this, gnome-terminal or tmux or my OS itself (Ubuntu Natty). Any ideas on how to address this would be great.

**Update**: I checked without tmux on a different terminal (LXTerminal) and the delay is present there too.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why my vim was acting strange. This question made me remember I had just started using it within screen. You saved my sanity.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Here's an actual fix. Add the following to `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -s escape-time 0
```

As mentioned in the comments: The server may need to be restarted. 
`tmux kill-server` kills the server; you may need to restart it. 
Alternatively, you can reload the configuration file
from the command prompt inside `tmux` by typing your tmux prefix
(default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) followed by **<kbd>:</kbd>**
and entering `source-file ~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Had a delay leaving insert mode in vim and hadn't really thought it might have been tmux interfering. This did the trick

Comment: As mentioned in http://superuser.com/questions/252214/slight-delay-when-switching-modes-in-vim-using-tmux-or-screen/252717#252717 I had to do `tmux kill-server` for this to take effect.

Comment: For anyone who arrived at this page trying to understand why there's a delay when switching from insert mode to command mode while using vi mode in bash, see http://superuser.com/a/1161871/236677

Comment: You can reload the configuration file by opening the command prompt inside tmux with `tmux-prefix` (default `Ctrl+b`) followed by `:` and entering `source-file $HOME/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: Well, now it works _instantly_. Any practical downsides to this solution in 2020?

Comment: Its worth mentioning this helps with the problem, but does not completely remove the ALT = ESC issue. You can still accidentally use ESC as ALT if you happen to press both at the same time, however, at least now there is no delay.

Answer (score 8):

The delay is caused by the input routines that may have to decide whether a function key was pressed or not. For this the input routine starts a timer whenever it reads in an ESC character. Characters that are read from the input before the timer runs out (let's say a tenth of a second) are then interpreted as ESC sequence of a function key and this ESC-sequence will be compared with known strings of ESC secuences from the terminfo or the termcap data base (depends on which low level routines are used).

Of cource this is annoying for applications where ESC is used on its own, but I don't know of any workaround for this.

Regarding your question with the behaviour of <kbd>ESC a</kbd> = <kbd>Meta a</kbd>:

Meta keys were not available with all keyboards. As a workaround it was often allowed to use the ESC key to be pressed before the other key.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ktf. The delay is not present in gvim, only in the terminal (I checked without tmux and the delay is still there).

Comment: gvim does not suffer from this problem, because it gets the information which key was pressed from the X11 server (so it does not have to parse ESC sequences).

Comment: Ok, so I need to make my gnome-terminal behave the same way then.

Comment: the gnome-terminal is not the problem - the problem described affects only programs running *on* a terminal (or in a Terminal emulation) and has to parse function keys. You will experience the same behaviour, if you try *xterm* or KDE-Terminal for instance.

Comment: Yes, terminal emulator is what I meant, not specifically gnome-terminal. Bad wording :) Thanks.

Comment: "Meta keys were not available with all keyboards. As a workaround it was often allowed to use the ESC key to be pressed before the other key." Perhaps even predating that, ttys often only had seven-bit data interfaces; there was no eighth "meta bit", so you had to send an ESC for Meta. And nowadays UTF-8 is widespread, so even with eight-bit connections you can't use the high bit for Meta.

Comment: This is an old question, so I’ll just link here to an (almost-as-old) [answer I gave on Superuser](http://superuser.com/a/648046/92596) that explains how to get rid of the delay after hitting `<Esc>` in zsh’s vi mode.  Tl;dr:  It’s a combination of setting the special environment variable `$KEYTIMEOUT` to a very low value, and binding `<Esc>` to something innocuous in the `vicmd` keymap.

Answer (score 3):

While this may not directly fix your issue, I have found that I can use `<Ctrl> c` to exit out of insert mode. This can also be used to exit tmux's screen scrolling (which can be invoked using `<leader> PgUP`)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `<C-c>` to exit out of insert mode in regular use since it doesn't run the `InsertLeave` autocommand which some plugins might be watching for. See `:h i_CTRL-C`.