# Having to press `esc` twice to enter normal mode in vi on tmux

Tags: tmux, vi

I'm having a problem in TMUX, where in order to go to normal mode in VIM, it takes 2 key presses of "ESC", how do I fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jsotola How do I fix it?

Comment: If you press `Esc` a single time in insert mode and wait a second (or two), does the editor switch to normal mode? Or does it actually require another `Esc`? How does the editor behave on the same system outside of `tmux`?

Comment: Yes @Kusalananda, there seems to be a delay actually, the num of key presses don't have anything to do with it

Comment: Is this delay as pronounced outside of `tmux` on the same system? I'm trying to narrow down the source of the issue.

Comment: Is the issue identical to what's described here? [ESC key causes a small delay in terminal due to its Alt+ behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23138)

Comment: Yes, @Kusalananda, fixed it by setting `set -s escape-time 0` in tmux conf. Thanks